# Should I be using AutoFixture to test the Core element of my Onion, which has no dependancies?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, domain-driven-design, autofixture

This question follows on from my previous question here: [How to use OneTimeSetup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388619/how-to-use-onetimesetup) and specifically one of the answerers answer.  Please see the code below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyFixture
{
    IProduct Product;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        Product = fixture.Create<Product>();
    }
    //tests to follow
}
```

Is AutoMoq used to create mocks only? The reason I ask is because I was reading a question on here earlier where the answerer implied that it is also used to create normal types i.e. not Mocks.

I want to test the Core element of my Onion, which has no dependencies.  Therefore should I be using AutoFixture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *AutoMoq* Glue Library gives AutoFixture the additional capabilities of an [Auto-Mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container); that is, not only can it compose normal objects for you - it can also supply mock objects to your objects, should they be so required.

AutoFixture itself is not an Auto-Mocking Container, but rather a library that automates the *Fixture Setup* phase of the *Four Phase Test* pattern, as described in [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054). It also enables you to automate code associated with the [Test Data Builder](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html) pattern.

It was explicitly designed as an alternative to *Implicit Setup*, so I think it makes little sense to use it together with a setup method and mutable class field as this question suggests. In other words, the whole point of AutoFixture is that it enables you to write independent unit tests like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        var product = fixture.Create<Product>();

        // Use product, and whatever else fixture creates, in the test
    }
}
```

You definitely can use it to test your units even when they have no dependencies, but in that case, you probably don't need the *AutoMoq* Customization.